# How do I change XTick format in NVD3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I would like to change the XTick format of the small chart to also be a date. I have the following which is lifted from [this example](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/lineWithFocus.html):

```
function chart(div)
{
var testdata = loadData();
nv.addGraph(function() {

    var chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart();

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
       var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
       return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
     });

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

   chart.y2Axis
       .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

   d3.select(div + ' svg')
       .datum(loadData())
     .transition().duration(500)
       .call(chart);

   nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

   return chart;
 });
 }
```

But only the large chart's format changes to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of fixing the ticks for the second x-axis.

The first way is by setting the `tickFormat` explicitly for the second axis as well. This design follows the traditional paradigm of setting one attribute at a time.

```js
var xFormat = function(d) {
   var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
   return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx));
};

chart.xAxis.tickFormat(xFormat);
chart.xAxis2.tickFormat(xFormat);
```

The second way, which would avoid code duplication, is setting both the axis together using a special function exposed by the `chart` API:

```js
// This would set both the axis simultaneously
chart.xTickFormat(xFormat);
```

This function is present in the code ([introduced here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/commit/ef3a7aefb0aab9786ab6d5b8c58c19370d8e0b46#L2R336)) for exactly this purpose. However, as the API is not very stable, it might be removed later.